# Scrapy using older version of OpenSSL

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, openssl

I am running into errors because my [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) is using an older version of `openssl` (OpenSSL 0.9.8zh). I upgraded my `openssl` version (1.0.2h) using `brew install openssl` but I don't think Scrapy is using it and maybe using the wrong version. I read somewhere that I should not be removing my older version but rather linking the newer version to a command that used to call the older version.

I suspect that Scrapy uses OpenSSL 0.9.8zh. How can `openssl version -v` use 1.0.2h?

```
$ openssl version -v
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl

$ /usr/local/bin/openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried these commands but nothing was working. However, after rebooting my computer it did the trick and I was able to use `scrapy` on websites with SSL

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
$ brew link --force openssl
$ reboot
```